# Category Magento second

Tags: magento

Hello i have a problem there is some one how want a second category

I will show in two printscreens

1st printscreen is good http://awesomescreenshot.com/07e30c7j58

But the second printscreen it wil not work

http://awesomescreenshot.com/07a30c7zad

i have try many things in de xml structure

Hope any one can help

Answer (score 0):

Login to your site backend and navigate to Catalog >> Manage Categories and then click on the desired category, select the **Display settings** tab and set **Yes** for **Is Anchor** and save the category.